# Running Javascript code through NodeJS

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, dom

I need help on running javascript code through NodeJS. So far I have the following code;

```
txt="<bookstore><book>";
txt=txt+"<title>Everyday Italian</title>";
txt=txt+"<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>";
txt=txt+"<year>2005</year>";
txt=txt+"</book></bookstore>";

parser=new DOMParser();
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0];
x.nodeValue="Diffrent Title";
```

I have it as test.js and I run it in the commant prompt as

```
node test.js
```

But it gives the following error:

```
ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined
```

What as I doing wrong here. Can any one help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS does not run inside browser so the DOMParser is not available. However you can use **jsdom**. Its provided by nodejs. And [its available](https://npmjs.org/package/jsdom) in node package manager.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
jsdom.env({
    html: txt,
    scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
    done: function(errors, window) {
        x = window.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0];
        x.nodeValue="Diffrent Title";
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks shiplu, But it gives an error.D:\Web\Node\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:177
    features   = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.document.implementation._fea
                                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'implementation' of undefined
    at exports.env.exports.jsdom.env.processHTML (D:\Web\Node\node_modules\jsdom
\lib\jsdom.js:177:59)
    at Object.exports.env.exports.jsdom.env (D:\Web\Node\node_modules\jsdom\lib\
jsdom.js:268:5)

Comment: Did you install jsdom? Usually its done by `npm install jsdom`

Comment: yes I installed it. I installed without any trouble. I run this in windows vista.

Comment: jsdom [hasn't implemented DOMParser yet](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/370).

Answer (score 3):

Node.js is running separate from the browser, so you don't get any browser-provided functions. `DOMParser` is a browser-provided class, and since Node.js runs on a server, there's no browser to provide it. If you want to communicate with your document you'll have to use another method.

Comment: Is there any way that I can pass a XML to a js function from nodeJS?